# How can set timeout Task which run some consuming and not loop function?

Tags: task

I find that timeout task by google, just like below:

```
 private async void CancelClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
      var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

      try
      {
          cts.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));//limited to 3 seconds
          await Test2(cts.Token);
      }
      catch
      {
          MessageBox.Show("TimeOut");
      }          
} 

private async Task Test2(CancellationToken ct)
{            
     for (int i=0;i<50;i++)
     {
         string TimeStr = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
         System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"D:\USER\Desktop\2.txt", TimeStr + '\n');
            
         await Task.Delay(1000, ct);
     }            
}
```

Above method it's work, but the situation I am facing is that
i cannot insert await Task.Delay(1000, ct) inside the loop.

because the time consuming funtion is third-party dll provide, like below:

private async Task Test2(CancellationToken ct)
{
//time co`your text`nsuming funtion, it is not in loop
imageprcess();
}
I hope imageprcess()  can finish within a certain time, if overtime, terminate

How can i do?
please help me, thanks